# Is the gram matrix associated with an exponential kernel, always Positive Definite? ( I already know its psotive semidefinite)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $$g(x,y) = e^{-|x-y|}$$

Does the gram matrix $G = [g(x_i,x_j)]$ always psitive definite? It is known that it atleast positive semidefinite. I'd like to know if it is positive definite as well?

Comment: Not necessarily.  For instance, if $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots  = x_n$, then the Gram matrix will have rank $1$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Excepting that case of all being same, assume no two points are same. Its a gram matrix

Comment: How exactly is your matrix a [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)?  Is there an inner product and set of vectors $v_i$ such that $G_{ij} = \langle v_i,v_j\rangle$?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju: I respectfully think that you should upvote & accept kimchi-lover's answer. It is very good.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro : Couldn't agree more. I had seen this answer but was busy for past few days. Thanks for pinging and reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\gamma(x):=e^{-|x|}=\frac 1 \pi \int_{\mathbb R} \frac {e^{itu}}{1+u^2}du,$$ we have $$\sum_{jk}a_j\bar a_k \gamma(x_j-x_k)=\frac 1 \pi \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{\left|\sum a_k e^{ix_ku}\right|^2}{1+u^2}du,\tag{*}$$
for any finite collection of $a_j\in \mathbb C$ and $x_j\in\mathbb R.$  If the matrix $G$ is *not* positive definite, then there would be some "witness" $a_k$ and $x_k$ such that the integral in (*)  vanished.  That would imply that $\sum_k a_k\exp(ix_ku)=0$ for almost all $u$.  This cannot happen if the $x_k$ for which $a_k\ne 0$  are distinct.  That is, if the $x_k$ are distinct, the matrix $G$ is strictly positive definite.

Further,  one can write $g(x,y)=\gamma(x-y)=C(K_0*K_0)(x-y)$ for some constant $C$, where $K_0$ is a [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) using the formula $$ K_0(x)=\frac 1 2 \int_{\mathbb R}\frac{e^{itx}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}dt.$$
This exhibits $G$ as a Gram matrix in the strict sense: $g(x,y)$ is the inner product of $K_0$ translated by $x$ and $K_0$ translated by $y$.

Comment: Very good answer. I have a follow-up question. You clearly show that strict positive definiteness follows from the Fourier transform of $\gamma$ being everywhere strictly positive. What happens if the Fourier transform has zeros? I gather that, if the zeros are a set of positive measure, then the function is only positive semi-definite. **What if the Fourier transform vanishes on a set of measure zero?**

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks! The trigonometric polynomial $\sum a_k\exp(ia_k t)$ either vanishes on a set of measure 0 or everywhere; and our assumptions about  $a_k$ and $x_k$ rule out the latter case.  So if the Fourier transform is positive on any set of positive measure, the integral is positive.

Comment: @kimchilover : What happens if I consider $g(x,y) = e^{|x-y|} + e^{x-y}+ e^{y-x}$

Comment: Have you tested this numerically, say on $2\times2$ matrices?

Comment: @kimchilover : I have tested, and it has both positive and negative eigen values. I have computed over a 6x6 gram matrix.

Comment: So we agree: your newest $g$ is not even positive *semi* definite.

Comment: @kimchilover : With the new $g$, I am expecting the matrix $G+I$ is non singular. It may be neither positive semidefinite nor negative semi definite. But i want it to be just non singular as long as all points are distinct. No two are same.

Comment: @kimchilover : Sorry I had an error in my calculations. I have tested now and it is positive definite. All eigen values are positive, for the newest $g$ mentioned in my comments.

Comment: At the least, it is positive semidefinite.